# Is there a way to display an out of stock message in the cart to specifically indicate which items have sold out?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, hook-woocommerce

Currently, our customers checked on their list of products added on cart like sometime ago and notice that 2 or 3 products are gone as it turns out, the product is out of stock.

Default functionality: Remove products on the shopping cart once it is out of stock.

We have our store set so that when an item is out of stock, a customer cannot add it to their cart. However, if an item is added to a cart and then goes out of stock before that customer checks out, the client want the product not deleted in the list under cart page but add a text "out of stock".

This situation usually occurs when:

A customer returns to their abandoned cart and an item in their cart has sold out.
A customer is shopping for a popular product and adds it to their cart, but then the item goes out of stock while the customer is still shopping or decides to check out

Is there a way to have WooCommerce automatically add an "out of stock" text on the product lists in cart.

Comment: Do you have product/inventory/manage stock set? Does your cart not show an error message if an included item has gone out of stock? If not, are you using a cart management plugin or custom template or functions? Anyway, there are a host of filters in the standard cart template that you might be able to exploit.

Answer (score 2):

```
add_filter('woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'woocommerce_cart_item_show_outofstock', 10, 3);

function woocommerce_cart_item_show_outofstock($item_name, $cart_item, $cart_item_key) {

    if ('outofstock' === $cart_item['data']->get_stock_status()) {

        $item_name .= "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<i style='color:#e2401c;'>" . __('Out of stock', 'woocommerce') . "</i>";
    }

    return $item_name;
}
```

Add this to your active theme `functions.php` file.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[Check this blog](https://njengah.com/woocommerce-show-product-stock-on-the-cart-page/)
This will show a message like "99 in stock" or "out of stock" if item is sold out

```
 add_action( 'woocommerce_after_cart_item_name','njengah_stock_and_backorder_cart_item_title', 9999, 2 );

 function njengah_stock_and_backorder_cart_item_title($cart_item,$cart_item_key ) {
 
 $product = $cart_item['data'];
 if ( $product->backorders_require_notification() && $product->is_on_backorder( $cart_item['quantity'] ) ) return;   
  echo wc_get_stock_html( $product );
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but the default functionality on the cart page will delete the product if the variation is deleted or out of stock. 

I'm trying to achieve is to not delete the product on the lists but rather add a text "out of stock" on the product. This is when a returning customer clicked on their abandoned cart that is expected to have a number of products added.

If one or all previously added products is "out of stock" or their variations are deleted on the back end will still show up on the list but has a text that says "out of stock".